# Resolve Autofac dependencies in OWIN Startup class

Tags: c#, owin, autofac

I have a multi-tenant MVC5 webapp, which is using Autofac v3.5.2 and Autofac.Mvc5 v3.3.4.

My Autofac DI wiring takes place in a class within my MVC project. For authentication, we are using [OWIN OpenId middleware](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2473126&seqNum=2) to integrate with Azure B2C. In the OWIN Startup class I need a dependency to set `tenantId`/`clientId` using information from the current request. 
I try to grab the dependency via :

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<...>();
```

However, this always throws an `ObjectDisposedException`

> Instances cannot be resolved and nested lifetimes cannot be created from this LifetimeScope as it has already been disposed.

We have an ISiteContext in our application that has a request-lifetime. It gets populated with configuration values specific to the current request. I am trying to fetch these values like this:

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
{
    var options = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                ...
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = SetSettingsForRequest
            }
        }
}

private Task SetSettingsForRequest(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
{
    var siteContext = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISiteContext>();
    context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = siteContext.ClientId;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

The error happens when trying to use the DependencyResolver in SetSettingsForRequest. I have no clue as to what I am doing wrong here. Currently I have no *Autofac* DI setup in my Startup `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` method, since this is already setup in my MVC project.

Comment: Could you share more code ? How did you try to get `tenantId` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I added a code sample that shows where I am trying to resolve the dependency to get a per-request clientId

Answer (score 2):

As Mickaël Derriey pointed out, the following code is a solution to being able to resolve request-scoped dependencies in OWIN:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        // Register dependencies, then...
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds
        // Autofac-injected middleware registered with the container.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

        // ...then register your other middleware not registered
        // with Autofac.
    }
}
```

and then use in any later code to resolve a dependency:

```
// getting the OWIN context from the OWIN context parameter
var owinContext = context.OwinContext;
var lifetimeScope = owinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(); 
var siteContext = lifetimeScope.GetService<ISiteContext>();
context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = siteContext.ClientId;
```

Using this solution, I did not have any issues anymore resolving request-scoped dependencies, since Autofac seems to accord to the OWIN way of creating/disposing of a request scope.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that at this point you need to set up DI in the OWIN pipeline. It's not a difficult operation.

You'll have to:

- follow the steps listed [in the official documentation on OWIN integration with ASP.NET MVC](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#owin-integration)
- move your existing registration code (that is most probably in `Global.asax.cs` in `Startup.cs` as the documentation linked above shows

Doing this means Autofac will create the per-request lifetime scope lower in the stack, at the OWIN level. This will allow you to get hold of the HTTP request lifetime scope from the OWIN context:

```cs
private Task SetSettingsForRequest(RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
{
    // getting the OWIN context from the OIDC notification context
    var owinContext = context.OwinContext;

    // that's an extension method provided by the Autofac OWIN integration
    // see https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Owin/blob/1e6eab35b59bc3838bbd2f6c7653d41647649b01/src/Autofac.Integration.Owin/OwinContextExtensions.cs#L19
    var lifetimeScope = owinContext.GetAutofacLifetimeScope(); 

    var siteContext = lifetimeScope.GetService<ISiteContext>();
    context.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = siteContext.ClientId;
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

I hope this helps you get over that issue.

Comment: Will try out your suggestion and document the result here. Thanks!